# Printing GeckoWebBrowser Control in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, gecko

I am working with GeckoWebBrowser control in vb.net winform, I wan to print the page contents direct to default printer.

I couldn't find and helping material so I was trying to take the page's screenshot and print, but it misses right after first page.
I am using `MicrosoftPowerPack` library.
Below is the code which I am trying to print the page.

```
    Dim settings As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
    PrintForm1.PrinterSettings = settings
    settings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.CompatibleModeFullWindow)
```

Comment: You can take a screenshot of the broswer and then print that. If you want screenshot code i can give it.

Comment: It will pleasure if you share.. I did many things. But in vain

Comment: I wrote it as an answer.

Comment: But ban tell you. What.. These sort of experiments have done in two days quest..

Comment: It doesn't print the whole page rather the visible page..

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry. I will try to write a solution :)

Comment: No issues.. I was running g out of time so I delayed to implement any logic

Comment: Do you mind if your program works only online?

Comment: No.. It's on for me.....

Comment: I expected it to be easier :(

Comment: Ok i found the solution but you must be online. I now writing it.

Comment: I wrote the solution. You have to be online for it to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code outputs a page to a png file: (Althought its slow and it freezes your program while it's running. Try putting it to a background worker to avoid freezing)

It's slow because it saves very high resolution images. But it depends on your internet speed.

Put that on the very top of your code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
```

The sub is:

```
Dim logincookie As CookieContainer
Public Sub urltoimage(ByVal url As String, ByVal pth As String)
    Dim postdata As String = "websiteurl=" & url & "&filetype=PNG&source=WEENYSOFT&convert=Convert+Now%21"
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postdata)
    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://s2.pdfconvertonline.com/convert/convert-webpage-win.php"), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
    postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postReq.Referer = "http://s2.pdfconvertonline.com/convert/convert-webpage-win.php"
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
    tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
    logincookie = tempCookies
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream)
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    Dim tb As New TextBox
    tb.Text = thepage
    For Each l In tb.Lines
        If l.Contains("pdfconvertonline.com/convert/") AndAlso l.Contains(".png") AndAlso l.Contains("http://") Then
            Dim i As Integer = l.IndexOf("http://")
            Dim f As String = "h" & l.Substring(i + 1, l.IndexOf("""", i + 1) - i - 1).Replace(" ", "")
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(f, pth)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Ex. `urltoimage("www.stackoverflow.com", "C:\Users\user\Desktop\stck.png")`

Replace `www.stackoverflow.com` with you website and `C:\Users\user\Desktop\stck.png` with you output image path.

Usage: `urltoimage(website, path)`

Ps. Whoever understands this code you know how dumb it is :) ..... But it works !

Comment: If it doesn't work tell me what version of gecko you are using.

Comment: Yet not, in fact busy with other task

Comment: I was busy with other tasks.. So tomorrow will give it a try

Comment: apparently the code looks OK, I did try but unfortunately couldn't retrieve the results due to network security here, but thanks you have given me new direction to solve problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub ShowPrintDialog()
    Dim print = Xpcom.QueryInterface(Of nsIWebBrowserPrint)(Me.Window.DomWindow)
    Try
        print.Print(print.GetGlobalPrintSettingsAttribute, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

That's the code for printing in geckofx.

Print Preview in the other hand is something else, i wasn't able to make it work so far.

https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-22.0/issues/10/print-preview-now-in-detail

https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-18.0/issues/54/print-preview

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot function is:

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot(ByVal Control As Control) As Bitmap
    Dim tmpImg As New Bitmap(Control.Width, Control.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImg)
        g.CopyFromScreen(Control.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)), New Point(0, 0), New Size(Control.Width, Control.Height))
    End Using
    Return tmpImg
End Function
```

Usage: `TakeScreenShot(WebBroswer1).Save("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)`

Replace `WebBroswer1` with your GeckoWebBroswer and `C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test.png` with your image path.

Then you can print the image.